# Cannot access task instance to get xcom

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-xcom

I am new to using xcoms in Airflow.

Here's what my code looks like:

```py
with DAG(default_args=default_args,
         max_active_runs=1,
         dag_id="my_dag",
         catchup=False,
         start_date=start_date,
         render_template_as_native_obj=True,
         schedule_interval=None) as my_dag:

    init_task = GKEStartPodOperator(
        task_id="init_task",
        name="init_task",
        retries=0,
        do_xcom_push=True,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        location=REGION,
        cluster_name=CLUSTER,
        image=image,
        arguments=[],
        in_cluster=False,
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        startup_timeout_seconds=300,
        namespace=NAMESPACE,
        service_account_name=SA,
    )


    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_1",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_kwargs={
            'connector_key':"e_conns",
        },
        python_callable=lambda: do_task(),
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_2",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_kwargs={
            'connector_key':"f_conns",
        },
        python_callable=lambda: do_task(),
    )
    init_task >> task_1 >> task_2

def do_task(**kwargs) -> int:
    ti = kwargs['ti']   
    connectors = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='init_task')[kwargs['connector_key']]
    #remainder removed (not relevant)
```

I can see that the xcom push from `init_task` is successful, but the `do_task` method is unable to pull xcom values. I get an error `KeyError: 'ti'` on `ti = kwargs['ti']`.

I've seen numerous ways to handle xcoms and I'm a little confused. I thought that Airflow would inject the task instance for the key `ti` into `kwargs`, but it doesn't seem like the task instance is ever getting to the method for the PythonOperator.

Is there a way to get the task instance into the method?

(Airflow is version 2.4.3 on GCP Composer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel silly and a little embarrassed. It seems I don't know Python as well as I thought I did.

I had declared my methods *after* the DAG, which was a mistake. Also, I had referenced the method as lambda, which wasn't necessary.

Code like this works fine:

```py
def do_task(ti, **kwargs) -> int:
    connectors = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='init_task')[kwargs['connector_key']]


with DAG(default_args=default_args,
         max_active_runs=1,
         dag_id="my_dag",
         catchup=False,
         start_date=start_date,
         render_template_as_native_obj=True,
         schedule_interval=None) as my_dag:

    init_task = GKEStartPodOperator(
        task_id="init_task",
        name="init_task",
        retries=0,
        do_xcom_push=True,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        location=REGION,
        cluster_name=CLUSTER,
        image=image,
        arguments=[],
        in_cluster=False,
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        startup_timeout_seconds=300,
        namespace=NAMESPACE,
        service_account_name=SA,
    )


    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_1",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_kwargs={
            'connector_key':"e_conns",
        },
        python_callable=do_task,
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_2",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_kwargs={
            'connector_key':"f_conns",
        },
        python_callable=do_task,
    )
    init_task >> task_1 >> task_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly reference the output of one task as the input of another:

```py
def do_task(some_value, connector_key):
    print(f"The output of init_task is {some_value[connector_key]}")

with DAG(...) as dag:
    init_task = GKEStartPodOperator(
        ...
    )


    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_1",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_kwargs={
            "some_value": init_task.output, # referenced here
            'connector_key':"e_conns",
        },
        python_callable=do_task,
    )

    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_2",
        do_xcom_push=False,
        op_kwargs={
            "some_value": init_task.output, # referenced here
            'connector_key':"f_conns",
        },
        python_callable=do_task,
    )
```

Comment: This looks so much easier than mucking around with xcoms! Why isn't this the main approach in the documentation? I'm going to try this out now.

Comment: I ended up not using `output`, but your answer pointed out an error in my code, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Yusuf Ganiyu just posted, here's a sample code

In your DAG:

```py
sampleTask = PythonOperator(
    task_id="task_id_goes_here",
    python_callable=pythonFunction,
    provide_context=True, # very important
    op_kwargs={"test": "testing"}, #if you have parameters
    dag=dag
)
```

In your python function:

```py
def pythonFunction(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    result = ti.xcom_pull(key='here_is_the_key', task_ids='task_id_where_you_push_to_x_com')
```

Answer (score -1):

`task.output` works really well but if you want it to be handled in a different way, usually you pull from x_com by:

```
result = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='TASK_ID_HERE', key='KEY_HERE')
```

Those are the only two required params.

You may also want to ensure you're able serialise the data you're pushing to x_com so it's easily deserialised.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I couldn't access `ti` from the callable.

Comment: It's best practice to access the `ti` inside the callable not outside in the dag parameters. You can do that from the `def sampleFunction(**kwargs): ti = kwargs['ti']`

Comment: To expand on @YusufGaniyu's comment, the issue you are having is that you are not allowing any keyword arguments to be passed to your lambda, hence `context`, `kwargs`, etc, aren't available